# Unit test Azure Event Hub Trigger (Azure Function)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure Function which is an EventHub Trigger. The events are being processed in a batch (EventData[]).

```
[FunctionName("EventHubTriggerCSharp")]
public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] EventData[] eventHubMessages, ILogger log)
{
    foreach (var message in eventHubMessages)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# function triggered to process a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
        log.LogInformation($"EnqueuedTimeUtc={message.SystemProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc}");
        await service.CallAsync(message);
    }
}
```

I would like to unit test the above method. But not sure how to pass the EventData[] parameter to this method. After searching for a long time and not finding a way I decided to ask this question.

Is it possible to unit test the above method? Maybe atleast be able to verify the service method is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to construct the array of `EventData` and pass that to the `Run` method along with a mock logger instance.

I have used MsTest but it should be the same logic with NUnit.

```
[TestClass]
public class EventHubTriggerCSharpTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IService> _mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    private readonly Mock<ILogger> _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();

    private EventHubTriggerCSharp _eventHubTriggerCSharp;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _eventHubTriggerCSharp = new EventHubTriggerCSharp(_mockService.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task WhenEventHubTriggersFunction_ThenCallAsyncWithEventHubMessage()
    {
        // arrange
        var data = "some data";

        var eventHubMessages = new List<EventData>
        {
            new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))
            {
                SystemProperties = new EventData.SystemPropertiesCollection(1, DateTime.Now, "offset", "partitionKey")
            }
        };

        // act
        await _eventHubTriggerCSharp.Run(eventHubMessages.ToArray(), _mockLogger.Object);

        // assert
        _mockService.Verify(x => x.CallAsync(eventHubMessages[0]));
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't actually run the test due to an issue with my Visual Studio but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Yes that did work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried using the code from WhenEventHubtTriggersFunction_ThenCallAsyncWithEventHubMessage and I am still getting "Property or indexer EventData.SystemProperties cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: Also got "SystemPropertiesCollection does not exist in the type 'EventData'"

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, with the below example you can use unit test the Azure Functions.
- Here is the example Test class for the unit test of Azure function.

```html
    {  
        "id": 1,  
        "CustomerName": "Test User",  
        "Country": "India",  
        "JoiningDate": "28-09-2020",  
        "PrimeUser": false  
    }
```

- And here is the Example test class for Azure Event hub unit test

```html
 from unittest.mock import MagicMock
    from unittest.mock import patch
    from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblob import BlobCheckpointStore
    from azure.eventhub import PartitionContext, EventData
    import unittest
    class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
        @patch('azure.eventhub.EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string')
        @patch('azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblob.BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string')
        def test_eventhub_receive_events(self, mock_blob_checkpoint_store, mock_event_hub_consumer_client):
            mock_event_hub_consumer_client.return_value = MagicMock()
            mock_blob_checkpoint_store.return_value = MagicMock()
            def receive(on_event, **kwargs):
                partition_context = MagicMock()
                partition_context.update_checkpoint = MagicMock()
                on_event(partition_context, EventData("test for Mock"))
            mock_event_hub_consumer_client.receive = receive
            with self.assertLogs('myprogram', level='INFO') as assert_execute:
                receive_events(mock_event_hub_consumer_client)
            self.assertIn("Accepting the event", assert_execute.output[0])
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

- Below are the Microsoft Documents about unit test in Azure functions for further information.

1. [Azure Function Unit Test](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-unit-tests-for-azure-functions/)
2. [Azure Eventhub Trigger Unit Test](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10846)
3. [Add Unit Tets to Azure Functions](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/add-unit-tests-to-your-functions)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, unit testing using nunit and moq (C#).